# LibGDX - Intellij - Add Jar

Tags: android, jar, gradle, libgdx, noclassdeffounderror

I have followed documentation on how to add an external jar to the libgdx project, added jar to a new folder called "libs" inside core project, then:

**build.gradle:**

```
project(":core") {
  apply plugin: "java"


  dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  }
}
```

notice **compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')** inside dependecies.
Then open Gradle view panel and refresh.
After all this when i try to debug on an Android device, it throws NoClassDefFoundError exception.

What am i doing wrong? i can debug for desktop.

Im adding jlayer from JavaZoom.

Comment: Is this .jar that you added plattform-independent? If the .jar is supposed to work only in Android then you will have to add it to the android project instead of the core project.

Comment: what do you mean by "work only in Android"? im trying to use the BasicPlayer from JavaZoom (http://www.javazoom.net/jlgui/api.html) to play a Shoutcast radio

Comment: Ok, so i added "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')" to the Android project inside build.gradle and copy the jar to libs inside Android project directory, now does not throw that error, apparently was some problem with gradle and android. Problem now is that it throws VerifyError, will make a new question with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i added "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')" to the Android project inside build.gradle and copy the jar to libs inside Android project directory, now does not throw that error, apparently was some problem with gradle and android. Problem now is that it throws VerifyError, will make a new question with that. –

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

line. If your libs folder is in core project's folder, add above line to

```
project(":core") {...

    dependencies {....
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

part of your build.gradle file. And add below line to your Android project's part in the build.gradle file.

```
project(":android") {...

    dependencies {....
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

Android must have this line but it is not necessary for other projects.